# What library exists for the construction of AFP documents in different languages?

Tags: build, afp

I am currently looking for a library in any language that allows me to create structured AFP documents but so far I have not found any

Previously I tried to use a library called afp.lib belonging to java but this structure the document but lost bytes which distorts the document

I hope the guide of some language that allows me the construction of AFP without loss of bytes. even just the library that allows me to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try https://github.com/yan74/afplib which is a JAVA library for reading and writing AFP. It is however very low-level so you get fine-grained access to all structured fields, triplets, and such. You need to have detailed knowledge on MO:DCA in order to make use of it. If you want to create documents a composer is better suited: [Apache FOP](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/)